# How to start kivy app with arguments from another kivy app

Tags: python, class, kivy

I want a variable from a textinput to be passed to another class upon start. So I have a class that is a loginscreen (done with python with kivy), when the user enters it's username I want this to be passed along to another class (in a different .py file) so that the newly started class will be able to greet the user with its name.

How do I do this?

**login_screen.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
import user_specific_greeting_screen

class LoginUser():
    def__init__(self):
        pass

def login(self):
    username_to_pass_on = self.user.text
    self.canvas.clear()
    user_specific_greeting_screen.ReturnApp2().run()  # <----  Want to pass var: 
                                                      #         username_to_pass_on
    

class  ReturnApp1(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginUser()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReturnApp1().run()
```

**returnapp1.kv:**

```
<LoginUser>:
    user: user_kv
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: user_kv
                hint_text: 'input username'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Login'
                on_press: root.login()
```

**user_specific_greeting_screen.py**

```
from kivy.app import App

class UserGreet():
    def __init__(self):
        self.label.text = 'Hello ' + username_i_want_passed  # <--- Want username inserted 
                                                             #      here from app_1.py

class ReturnApp2(App):
    def build(self):
        return UserGreet()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReturnApp2().run()
```

**returnapp2.kv:**

```
<UserGreet>:
    label: label_kv
    Label:
        id: label_kv
```

I hope the code explains what I would like to do.
Also, am I thinking about this 'correctly' as a whole? I mean with one .py file for login-screen and another for user-specific-greeting screen etc? Learning both kivy and python and programming at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you need to start another App? Couldn't you just show another `Screen` that shows the "user-specific-greeting"? Have a look at [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager).

Comment: Feeling like a knob, but this is probably exactly what I need to look into. Thanks alot for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making 2 different python and kivy files, you should use the `ScreenManager()` in Kivy. This allows you to create multiple `Screen()`, each with it's own set of widgets in one app.

**Python File (main.py)**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class LoginUserScreen(Screen):

    username_to_pass_on = ""

    def login(self):
        self.username_to_pass_on = self.ids["user_kv"].text
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.manager.current = "UserGreetScreen"


class UserGreetScreen(Screen):
    
    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids["label_kv"].text = 'Hello ' + self.manager.get_screen("LoginUserScreen").username_to_pass_on


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("styling.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginUserScreen())
        sm.add_widget(UserGreetScreen())
        return sm


MyApp().run()
```

**Kivy File (styling.kv)**

```
#:kivy 1.11.1


<LoginUserScreen>:
    name: "LoginUserScreen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2

        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: user_kv
                hint_text: 'input username'

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Login'
                on_press: root.login()


<UserGreetScreen>:
    name: "UserGreetScreen"

    Label:
        id: label_kv
```

**Things to note:**

1. When using screens, you can directly access IDs instead of having to create an attribute in the .kv file (`label: label_kv` is not needed, you can directly `self.ids["<widget id>"]`)
2. You declare Screens in both .py and .kv individually just like the master widget but both in one file
3. You need to give a name to every screen, this can be different than the class name, but keeping it same helps in consistency
4. Instead of switching apps, we are now switching screens using `self.manager.current = "ScreenName"`
5. I have made the `username_to_pass_on`, a property of the Screen, allowing easy access from any other screen
6. We use Builder to load the file and initialize the `ScreenManager()` in the build, and add the screens one by one and return the manager in the end.
7. In order to access the other screen's properties and widgets, you use `self.manager.get_screen("ScreenName").property` from a screen

Comment: @Sixtenson if it helped you, consider marking it as the correct one